# Plotly: Remove `trace0` by default

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

This is not a duplicate of [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60715706/how-to-remove-trace0-here)

Adding the `<extra></extra>` makes sure the `trace#` is removed from the graph. But is there a way I could make that the default setting?

[image]

I am creating a custom plotly theme and would like it to be the default setting, but it is included in the `trace` class and not the `layout` one. Also, adding it to every trace call in `plotly.go` call is repetitive.

To recreate the graph-

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

world_df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {494: '2021-05-09',
  495: '2021-05-10',
  496: '2021-05-11',
  497: '2021-05-12',
  498: '2021-05-13',
  499: '2021-05-14',
  500: '2021-05-15',
  501: '2021-05-16',
  502: '2021-05-17',
  503: '2021-05-18'},
 'total_deaths': {494: 3293029.0,
  495: 3303796.0,
  496: 3317412.0,
  497: 3331346.0,
  498: 3344481.0,
  499: 3357610.0,
  500: 3369259.0,
  501: 3379349.0,
  502: 3389992.0,
  503: 3404338.0}})

#Comment out line below for exact copy as the question (though I don't think it's necessary)
#world_df = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/vyaduvanshi/helper-files/raw/master/world_so.csv')

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, subplot_titles=['Normal Scale','Logarithmic Scale'])
fig.add_scatter(x=world_df.date, y=world_df.total_deaths, row=1, col=1,
                hovertemplate='Removed manually:%{y}<extra></extra>',line=dict(color='#DB2B39'))
fig.add_scatter(x=world_df.date, y=world_df.total_deaths, row=1, col=2, line=dict(color='#DB2B39'))
fig.update_yaxes(type="log", row=1, col=2)
fig.update_layout(title_text='Total Deaths', showlegend=False)
```

The template is this (very close to plotly default), just in case you need it

```
pio.templates['my_theme'] = go.layout.Template({
    'data': {'bar': [{'error_x': {'color': '#2a3f5f'},
                      'error_y': {'color': '#2a3f5f'},
                      'marker': {'line': {'color': '#E5ECF6', 'width': 0.5}},
                      'type': 'bar'}],
             'barpolar': [{'marker': {'line': {'color': '#E5ECF6', 'width': 0.5}}, 'type': 'barpolar'}],
             'carpet': [{'aaxis': {'endlinecolor': '#2a3f5f',
                                   'gridcolor': 'white',
                                   'linecolor': 'white',
                                   'minorgridcolor': 'white',
                                   'startlinecolor': '#2a3f5f'},
                         'baxis': {'endlinecolor': '#2a3f5f',
                                   'gridcolor': 'white',
                                   'linecolor': 'white',
                                   'minorgridcolor': 'white',
                                   'startlinecolor': '#2a3f5f'},
                         'type': 'carpet'}],
             'choropleth': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}, 'type': 'choropleth'}],
             'contour': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''},
                          'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'], [0.1111111111111111,
                                         '#46039f'], [0.2222222222222222,
                                         '#7201a8'], [0.3333333333333333,
                                         '#9c179e'], [0.4444444444444444,
                                         '#bd3786'], [0.5555555555555556,
                                         '#d8576b'], [0.6666666666666666,
                                         '#ed7953'], [0.7777777777777778,
                                         '#fb9f3a'], [0.8888888888888888,
                                         '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']],
                          'type': 'contour'}],
             'contourcarpet': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}, 'type': 'contourcarpet'}],
             'heatmap': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''},
                          'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'], [0.1111111111111111,
                                         '#46039f'], [0.2222222222222222,
                                         '#7201a8'], [0.3333333333333333,
                                         '#9c179e'], [0.4444444444444444,
                                         '#bd3786'], [0.5555555555555556,
                                         '#d8576b'], [0.6666666666666666,
                                         '#ed7953'], [0.7777777777777778,
                                         '#fb9f3a'], [0.8888888888888888,
                                         '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']],
                          'type': 'heatmap'}],
             'heatmapgl': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''},
                            'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'], [0.1111111111111111,
                                           '#46039f'], [0.2222222222222222,
                                           '#7201a8'], [0.3333333333333333,
                                           '#9c179e'], [0.4444444444444444,
                                           '#bd3786'], [0.5555555555555556,
                                           '#d8576b'], [0.6666666666666666,
                                           '#ed7953'], [0.7777777777777778,
                                           '#fb9f3a'], [0.8888888888888888,
                                           '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']],
                            'type': 'heatmapgl'}],
             'histogram': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'histogram'}],
             'histogram2d': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''},
                              'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'],
                                             [0.1111111111111111, '#46039f'],
                                             [0.2222222222222222, '#7201a8'],
                                             [0.3333333333333333, '#9c179e'],
                                             [0.4444444444444444, '#bd3786'],
                                             [0.5555555555555556, '#d8576b'],
                                             [0.6666666666666666, '#ed7953'],
                                             [0.7777777777777778, '#fb9f3a'],
                                             [0.8888888888888888, '#fdca26'], [1.0,
                                             '#f0f921']],
                              'type': 'histogram2d'}],
             'histogram2dcontour': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''},
                                     'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'],
                                                    [0.1111111111111111,
                                                    '#46039f'],
                                                    [0.2222222222222222,
                                                    '#7201a8'],
                                                    [0.3333333333333333,
                                                    '#9c179e'],
                                                    [0.4444444444444444,
                                                    '#bd3786'],
                                                    [0.5555555555555556,
                                                    '#d8576b'],
                                                    [0.6666666666666666,
                                                    '#ed7953'],
                                                    [0.7777777777777778,
                                                    '#fb9f3a'],
                                                    [0.8888888888888888,
                                                    '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']],
                                     'type': 'histogram2dcontour'}],
             'mesh3d': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}, 'type': 'mesh3d'}],
             'parcoords': [{'line': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'parcoords'}],
             'pie': [{'automargin': True, 'type': 'pie'}],
             'scatter': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scatter',
                         'line':{'width':2.5}}],
             'scatter3d': [{'line': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}},
                            'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}},
                            'type': 'scatter3d'}],
             'scattercarpet': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scattercarpet'}],
             'scattergeo': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scattergeo'}],
             'scattergl': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scattergl'}],
             'scattermapbox': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scattermapbox'}],
             'scatterpolar': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scatterpolar'}],
             'scatterpolargl': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scatterpolargl'}],
             'scatterternary': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scatterternary'}],
             'surface': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''},
                          'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'], [0.1111111111111111,
                                         '#46039f'], [0.2222222222222222,
                                         '#7201a8'], [0.3333333333333333,
                                         '#9c179e'], [0.4444444444444444,
                                         '#bd3786'], [0.5555555555555556,
                                         '#d8576b'], [0.6666666666666666,
                                         '#ed7953'], [0.7777777777777778,
                                         '#fb9f3a'], [0.8888888888888888,
                                         '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']],
                          'type': 'surface'}],
             'table': [{'cells': {'fill': {'color': '#EBF0F8'}, 'line': {'color': 'white'}},
                        'header': {'fill': {'color': '#C8D4E3'}, 'line': {'color': 'white'}},
                        'type': 'table'}]},
    'layout': {'annotationdefaults': {'arrowcolor': '#2a3f5f', 'arrowhead': 0, 'arrowwidth': 1},
               'autotypenumbers': 'strict',
               'coloraxis': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}},
               'colorscale': {'diverging': [[0, '#8e0152'], [0.1, '#c51b7d'],
                                            [0.2, '#de77ae'], [0.3, '#f1b6da'],
                                            [0.4, '#fde0ef'], [0.5, '#f7f7f7'],
                                            [0.6, '#e6f5d0'], [0.7, '#b8e186'],
                                            [0.8, '#7fbc41'], [0.9, '#4d9221'], [1,
                                            '#276419']],
                              'sequential': [[0.0, '#0d0887'],
                                             [0.1111111111111111, '#46039f'],
                                             [0.2222222222222222, '#7201a8'],
                                             [0.3333333333333333, '#9c179e'],
                                             [0.4444444444444444, '#bd3786'],
                                             [0.5555555555555556, '#d8576b'],
                                             [0.6666666666666666, '#ed7953'],
                                             [0.7777777777777778, '#fb9f3a'],
                                             [0.8888888888888888, '#fdca26'], [1.0,
                                             '#f0f921']],
                              'sequentialminus': [[0.0, '#0d0887'],
                                                  [0.1111111111111111, '#46039f'],
                                                  [0.2222222222222222, '#7201a8'],
                                                  [0.3333333333333333, '#9c179e'],
                                                  [0.4444444444444444, '#bd3786'],
                                                  [0.5555555555555556, '#d8576b'],
                                                  [0.6666666666666666, '#ed7953'],
                                                  [0.7777777777777778, '#fb9f3a'],
                                                  [0.8888888888888888, '#fdca26'],
                                                  [1.0, '#f0f921']]},
               'colorway': ["#db2b39","#faa613","#3d405b","#2fbf71","#00a6fb"],
               'font': {'color': '#2a3f5f'},
               'geo': {'bgcolor': 'white',
                       'lakecolor': 'white',
                       'landcolor': '#E5ECF6',
                       'showlakes': True,
                       'showland': True,
                       'subunitcolor': 'white'},
               'hoverlabel': {'align': 'left'},
               'hovermode': 'closest',
               'mapbox': {'style': 'light'},
               'paper_bgcolor': 'white',
               'plot_bgcolor': 'white',
               'polar': {'angularaxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': ''},
                         'bgcolor': '#E5ECF6',
                         'radialaxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': ''}},
               'scene': {'xaxis': {'backgroundcolor': '#E5ECF6',
                                   'gridcolor': 'white',
                                   'gridwidth': 2,
                                   'linecolor': 'white',
                                   'showbackground': True,
                                   'ticks': '',
                                   'zerolinecolor': 'white'},
                         'yaxis': {'backgroundcolor': '#E5ECF6',
                                   'gridcolor': 'white',
                                   'gridwidth': 2,
                                   'linecolor': 'white',
                                   'showbackground': True,
                                   'ticks': '',
                                   'zerolinecolor': 'white'},
                         'zaxis': {'backgroundcolor': '#E5ECF6',
                                   'gridcolor': 'white',
                                   'gridwidth': 2,
                                   'linecolor': 'white',
                                   'showbackground': True,
                                   'ticks': '',
                                   'zerolinecolor': 'white'}},
               'shapedefaults': {'line': {'color': '#2a3f5f'}},
               'ternary': {'aaxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': ''},
                           'baxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': ''},
                           'bgcolor': '#E5ECF6',
                           'caxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': ''}},
               'title': {'x': 0.5,
                        'font_size':30},
               'xaxis': {'automargin': True,
                         'gridcolor': '#eeeeee',
                         'linecolor': 'white',
                         'ticks': '',
                         'title': {'standoff': 15},
                         'zerolinecolor': 'white',
                         'zerolinewidth': 2},
               'yaxis': {'automargin': True,
                         'gridcolor': '#eeeeee',
                         'linecolor': 'white',
                         'ticks': '',
                         'title': {'standoff': 15},
                         'zerolinecolor': 'white',
                         'zerolinewidth': 2}}
})
```

Comment: Can you include the code you used to generate this template and plot?

Comment: @DerekO It's been done.

Comment: I have trouble reading your csv. Do you mind to check that line?

Comment: @rpanai I wonder why. I pasted my code in new ipynb file and it reads just fine. No errors.

Comment: @callmeanythingyouwant Please consider sharing a sample of your data [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163251/pandas-how-to-easily-share-a-sample-dataframe-using-df-to-dict/63163254#63163254) instead. It's much more robust and time saving both for yourself and those trying to help you.

Comment: @vestland Hi vestland, it's done.

Comment: @rpanai I don't see an immediate solution to this. Do you?

Comment: It is not clear to me if you want to use the given `hovertemplate` only or for all of them? In the second case you can just use `fig.update_traces`.

Comment: @rpanai I want to use it for all my graphs, but I was looking to make it a default setting. Passing `fig.update_traces` with every trace is a workaround but is rather repetitive and unclean.

Comment: @callmeanythingyouwant I understand it's not a layout solution but you can use one time for all possible traces within the same plot.

Comment: @vestland I found a solution. Had to pass it separately to each trace call though as using it in `update_layout` was only changing it for the second plot, probably something to do with `make_subplots()`. Adding it in the template though is an easy and neat solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interestingly enough, I found a solution that does the trick!

Passing `hoverlabel = dict(namelength=0)` to the trace calls removes the `trace#`. Same can be implemented by passing it in the template. Here's the complete code-

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

world_df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {494: '2021-05-09',
  495: '2021-05-10',
  496: '2021-05-11',
  497: '2021-05-12',
  498: '2021-05-13',
  499: '2021-05-14',
  500: '2021-05-15',
  501: '2021-05-16',
  502: '2021-05-17',
  503: '2021-05-18'},
 'total_deaths': {494: 3293029.0,
  495: 3303796.0,
  496: 3317412.0,
  497: 3331346.0,
  498: 3344481.0,
  499: 3357610.0,
  500: 3369259.0,
  501: 3379349.0,
  502: 3389992.0,
  503: 3404338.0}})

#Comment out line below for exact copy as the question (though I don't think it's necessary)
#world_df = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/vyaduvanshi/helper-files/raw/master/world_so.csv')

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, subplot_titles=['Normal Scale','Logarithmic Scale'])
fig.add_scatter(x=world_df.date, y=world_df.total_deaths, row=1, col=1,
                hovertemplate='Removed manually:%{y}',line=dict(color='#DB2B39'),
               hoverlabel=dict(namelength=0))
fig.add_scatter(x=world_df.date, y=world_df.total_deaths, row=1, col=2, line=dict(color='#DB2B39'),
               hoverlabel=dict(namelength=0))
fig.update_yaxes(type="log", row=1, col=2)
fig.update_layout(title_text='Total Deaths', showlegend=False)
```

Here's the same thing done in a template-

```
pio.templates['my_theme'] = go.layout.Template({
    'data': {'bar': [{'error_x': {'color': '#2a3f5f'},
                      'error_y': {'color': '#2a3f5f'},
                      'marker': {'line': {'color': '#E5ECF6', 'width': 0.5}},
                      'type': 'bar'}],
             'barpolar': [{'marker': {'line': {'color': '#E5ECF6', 'width': 0.5}}, 'type': 'barpolar'}],
             'carpet': [{'aaxis': {'endlinecolor': '#2a3f5f',
                                   'gridcolor': 'white',
                                   'linecolor': 'white',
                                   'minorgridcolor': 'white',
                                   'startlinecolor': '#2a3f5f'},
                         'baxis': {'endlinecolor': '#2a3f5f',
                                   'gridcolor': 'white',
                                   'linecolor': 'white',
                                   'minorgridcolor': 'white',
                                   'startlinecolor': '#2a3f5f'},
                         'type': 'carpet'}],
             'choropleth': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}, 'type': 'choropleth'}],
             'contour': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''},
                          'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'], [0.1111111111111111,
                                         '#46039f'], [0.2222222222222222,
                                         '#7201a8'], [0.3333333333333333,
                                         '#9c179e'], [0.4444444444444444,
                                         '#bd3786'], [0.5555555555555556,
                                         '#d8576b'], [0.6666666666666666,
                                         '#ed7953'], [0.7777777777777778,
                                         '#fb9f3a'], [0.8888888888888888,
                                         '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']],
                          'type': 'contour'}],
             'contourcarpet': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}, 'type': 'contourcarpet'}],
             'heatmap': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''},
                          'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'], [0.1111111111111111,
                                         '#46039f'], [0.2222222222222222,
                                         '#7201a8'], [0.3333333333333333,
                                         '#9c179e'], [0.4444444444444444,
                                         '#bd3786'], [0.5555555555555556,
                                         '#d8576b'], [0.6666666666666666,
                                         '#ed7953'], [0.7777777777777778,
                                         '#fb9f3a'], [0.8888888888888888,
                                         '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']],
                          'type': 'heatmap'}],
             'heatmapgl': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''},
                            'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'], [0.1111111111111111,
                                           '#46039f'], [0.2222222222222222,
                                           '#7201a8'], [0.3333333333333333,
                                           '#9c179e'], [0.4444444444444444,
                                           '#bd3786'], [0.5555555555555556,
                                           '#d8576b'], [0.6666666666666666,
                                           '#ed7953'], [0.7777777777777778,
                                           '#fb9f3a'], [0.8888888888888888,
                                           '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']],
                            'type': 'heatmapgl'}],
             'histogram': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'histogram'}],
             'histogram2d': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''},
                              'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'],
                                             [0.1111111111111111, '#46039f'],
                                             [0.2222222222222222, '#7201a8'],
                                             [0.3333333333333333, '#9c179e'],
                                             [0.4444444444444444, '#bd3786'],
                                             [0.5555555555555556, '#d8576b'],
                                             [0.6666666666666666, '#ed7953'],
                                             [0.7777777777777778, '#fb9f3a'],
                                             [0.8888888888888888, '#fdca26'], [1.0,
                                             '#f0f921']],
                              'type': 'histogram2d'}],
             'histogram2dcontour': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''},
                                     'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'],
                                                    [0.1111111111111111,
                                                    '#46039f'],
                                                    [0.2222222222222222,
                                                    '#7201a8'],
                                                    [0.3333333333333333,
                                                    '#9c179e'],
                                                    [0.4444444444444444,
                                                    '#bd3786'],
                                                    [0.5555555555555556,
                                                    '#d8576b'],
                                                    [0.6666666666666666,
                                                    '#ed7953'],
                                                    [0.7777777777777778,
                                                    '#fb9f3a'],
                                                    [0.8888888888888888,
                                                    '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']],
                                     'type': 'histogram2dcontour'}],
             'mesh3d': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}, 'type': 'mesh3d'}],
             'parcoords': [{'line': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'parcoords'}],
             'pie': [{'automargin': True, 'type': 'pie'}],
             'scatter': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scatter',
                         'line':{'width':2.5}}],
             'scatter3d': [{'line': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}},
                            'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}},
                            'type': 'scatter3d'}],
             'scattercarpet': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scattercarpet'}],
             'scattergeo': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scattergeo'}],
             'scattergl': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scattergl'}],
             'scattermapbox': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scattermapbox'}],
             'scatterpolar': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scatterpolar'}],
             'scatterpolargl': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scatterpolargl'}],
             'scatterternary': [{'marker': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}}, 'type': 'scatterternary'}],
             'surface': [{'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''},
                          'colorscale': [[0.0, '#0d0887'], [0.1111111111111111,
                                         '#46039f'], [0.2222222222222222,
                                         '#7201a8'], [0.3333333333333333,
                                         '#9c179e'], [0.4444444444444444,
                                         '#bd3786'], [0.5555555555555556,
                                         '#d8576b'], [0.6666666666666666,
                                         '#ed7953'], [0.7777777777777778,
                                         '#fb9f3a'], [0.8888888888888888,
                                         '#fdca26'], [1.0, '#f0f921']],
                          'type': 'surface'}],
             'table': [{'cells': {'fill': {'color': '#EBF0F8'}, 'line': {'color': 'white'}},
                        'header': {'fill': {'color': '#C8D4E3'}, 'line': {'color': 'white'}},
                        'type': 'table'}]},
    'layout': {'annotationdefaults': {'arrowcolor': '#2a3f5f', 'arrowhead': 0, 'arrowwidth': 1},
               'autotypenumbers': 'strict',
               'coloraxis': {'colorbar': {'outlinewidth': 0, 'ticks': ''}},
               'colorscale': {'diverging': [[0, '#8e0152'], [0.1, '#c51b7d'],
                                            [0.2, '#de77ae'], [0.3, '#f1b6da'],
                                            [0.4, '#fde0ef'], [0.5, '#f7f7f7'],
                                            [0.6, '#e6f5d0'], [0.7, '#b8e186'],
                                            [0.8, '#7fbc41'], [0.9, '#4d9221'], [1,
                                            '#276419']],
                              'sequential': [[0.0, '#0d0887'],
                                             [0.1111111111111111, '#46039f'],
                                             [0.2222222222222222, '#7201a8'],
                                             [0.3333333333333333, '#9c179e'],
                                             [0.4444444444444444, '#bd3786'],
                                             [0.5555555555555556, '#d8576b'],
                                             [0.6666666666666666, '#ed7953'],
                                             [0.7777777777777778, '#fb9f3a'],
                                             [0.8888888888888888, '#fdca26'], [1.0,
                                             '#f0f921']],
                              'sequentialminus': [[0.0, '#0d0887'],
                                                  [0.1111111111111111, '#46039f'],
                                                  [0.2222222222222222, '#7201a8'],
                                                  [0.3333333333333333, '#9c179e'],
                                                  [0.4444444444444444, '#bd3786'],
                                                  [0.5555555555555556, '#d8576b'],
                                                  [0.6666666666666666, '#ed7953'],
                                                  [0.7777777777777778, '#fb9f3a'],
                                                  [0.8888888888888888, '#fdca26'],
                                                  [1.0, '#f0f921']]},
               'colorway': ["#db2b39","#faa613","#3d405b","#2fbf71","#00a6fb"],
               'font': {'color': '#2a3f5f'},
               'geo': {'bgcolor': 'white',
                       'lakecolor': 'white',
                       'landcolor': '#E5ECF6',
                       'showlakes': True,
                       'showland': True,
                       'subunitcolor': 'white'},
               'hoverlabel': {'align': 'left',
                              'namelength': 0},
               'hovermode': 'closest',
               'mapbox': {'style': 'light'},
               'paper_bgcolor': 'white',
               'plot_bgcolor': 'white',
               'polar': {'angularaxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': ''},
                         'bgcolor': '#E5ECF6',
                         'radialaxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': ''}},
               'scene': {'xaxis': {'backgroundcolor': '#E5ECF6',
                                   'gridcolor': 'white',
                                   'gridwidth': 2,
                                   'linecolor': 'white',
                                   'showbackground': True,
                                   'ticks': '',
                                   'zerolinecolor': 'white'},
                         'yaxis': {'backgroundcolor': '#E5ECF6',
                                   'gridcolor': 'white',
                                   'gridwidth': 2,
                                   'linecolor': 'white',
                                   'showbackground': True,
                                   'ticks': '',
                                   'zerolinecolor': 'white'},
                         'zaxis': {'backgroundcolor': '#E5ECF6',
                                   'gridcolor': 'white',
                                   'gridwidth': 2,
                                   'linecolor': 'white',
                                   'showbackground': True,
                                   'ticks': '',
                                   'zerolinecolor': 'white'}},
               'shapedefaults': {'line': {'color': '#2a3f5f'}},
               'ternary': {'aaxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': ''},
                           'baxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': ''},
                           'bgcolor': '#E5ECF6',
                           'caxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white', 'ticks': ''}},
               'title': {'x': 0.5,
                        'font_size':30},
               'xaxis': {'automargin': True,
                         'gridcolor': '#eeeeee',
                         'linecolor': 'white',
                         'ticks': '',
                         'title': {'standoff': 15},
                         'zerolinecolor': 'white',
                         'zerolinewidth': 2},
               'yaxis': {'automargin': True,
                         'gridcolor': '#eeeeee',
                         'linecolor': 'white',
                         'ticks': '',
                         'title': {'standoff': 15},
                         'zerolinecolor': 'white',
                         'zerolinewidth': 2}}
})
```

Comment: Thats really interesting!